# Composer PHP script running old PHP version causing syntax errors?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I am using composer's `post-update-cmd` with Laravel. My code is written in PHP 7, I think composer's script call is running an old version because I am getting syntax error on executing `php artisan ide-helper:generate`. Running the command manually in terminal does not trigger any errors.

How do I specify or configure composer's php to use a specific php path? Using @php, does not seem to work as "artisan" as the path becomes invalid:

> You made a reference to a non-existent script @php artisan
>   ide-helper:generate

Here's my composer.json:

```
...
"post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan ide-helper:generate",
            "php artisan ide-helper:meta",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
...
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error?

Comment: `Error Output: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'` it's due to the colon for the return type `public function getIsPublishedAttribute():bool` Return types are only supported in PHP 7

Comment: go to command line and run `php -v` which will show u the `php cli` version. i think cli is not `php7`

Comment: @CerlinBoss php -v does show me it's  php 7. Running the php command manually in terminal shows no error, but when it's executed via composer's post-update-cmd gives me the error. So I am asking how do I check composer's php version and change it?

Comment: composer works with php cli so it will be using php 7 only

Comment: Nope, just checked. When I execute `composer exec 'php -v'` it is showing php 5. Maybe it has go to do with the fact that I replaced terminal with oh-my-zsh. Edit: I managed to get it's path too; It's using the path to php 5.

Comment: Then the cause is found... On which system are you? Depending on this the way to fix the problem changes...

Comment: I m on OSX. `vim ~/.bash_profile` is showing to correct path to php 7. So I am still wondering why composer's php path is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So composer is somehow running the old php even though my ~/.bash_profile is pointing php to a new version.

To prove it, executing `php -v` was showing PHP 7. Whereas executing `composer exec 'php -v'` was showing php 5.6.

So after being bothered by this for a few days, I finally tried this. Apparently, the order of ~/.bash_profile matters.

I changed this:

```
alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.8/bin:$PATH
```

To:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.8/bin:$PATH
alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"
```

and reload the profile by executing `source ~/.bash_profile`

Now `composer exec 'php -v'` shows php 7!

Answer (score 2):

I was receiving a similar error (my particular error was with the final script, @php artisan optimize)

Composer was already using PHP 7.1 correctly. Running composer selfupdate fixed this error.

Answer (score 0):

First check the version of your php.

by entering this command to your command prompt(cmd): `php -v`

If it's showing the wrong version there's a conflict happening.

find the conflicting app by finding the source of your php (cmd): `php --ini`

the prompt will now tell you where the file is coming from.
You can then uninstall the app that's hosting the old php file. Then your system should automatically use the newer php.